# Javascript loop logic error with Tone.js Tone.Transport.scheduleRepeat

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

Just playing around with [Tone.js](https://tonejs.github.io/docs/r13/Transport) and not quite understanding the finer points of `Tone.Transport.scheduleRepeat`

When using a function more than once the sounds start to distort and timing changes.

I'm following this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/0uXDdTyYBYQ?t=704), and trying to duplicate within [Codepen](https://codepen.io/paulywill/pen/MMdpax).

My "playScore" function changes every time I run it despite the index counter being reset to zero.

```
<!-- HTML -- >
<button onclick="playScore()">
  TEST SCORE
</button>



//js
function playScore() {
  console.clear();
  console.log("TEST SCORE");
  const synthScore = new Tone.Synth
  synthScore.oscillator.type = 'sine';
  synthScore.toMaster();
  //synth.triggerAttackRelease ('E4', '8n' );  
  const notes = [
    'C4', 'E4', 'G4',
    'C5', 'E5', 'G5' 
  ];

  let index = 0;

  Tone.Transport.scheduleRepeat(time => {
    repeat(time);
  }, "8n");

  function repeat(time) {
    console.log("index: " + index + " notes.length: " + notes.length);
    let note = notes[index % notes.length];
    synthScore.triggerAttackRelease(note, '8n', time);
    console.log("note:" + note + " time: " + time);
    index++;
  }

  Tone.Transport.start();

  setTimeout(() => {
    Tone.Transport.stop();
  }, 5000)

  // Tone.Transport.bpm.value = 120
```

I expect the same notes to be played the same way in the same order.

Instead, I'm seeing it change on each iteration.

I found that it's because apparently, I have 2 index variable and logic with local instance within the function and global outside that function.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a simple solution.
The button function "playScore" simply starts and stops the Tone.Transport
The notes pick up right where they let off rather than starting at the top of the array.

```
console.clear();

  const synthScore = new Tone.Synth
  synthScore.oscillator.type = 'sine';
  synthScore.toMaster();
  //synth.triggerAttackRelease ('E4', '8n' );  
  const notes = [
    'C4', 'E4', 'G4',
    'C5', 'E5', 'G5' 
  ]; 
  let speed = '8n'
  let index = 0;

  Tone.Transport.scheduleRepeat(time => {
    repeat(time);
  }, "8n");

  let repeat = ( time ) => {
    console.log("index: " + index + " notes.length: " + notes.length);
    let note = notes[index % notes.length];
    //console.log(note)
    synthScore.triggerAttackRelease(note, '8n', time);
    addOutput(note, '8n')  
    index++;
  }  


function playScore() {
  console.log("TEST SCORE");
  Tone.Transport.start();

  setTimeout(() => {
    Tone.Transport.stop();
  }, 5000);
  // Tone.Transport.bpm.value = 120  
}
```